# Hide table rows until search is performed

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have a basic SearchBar attached to a basic TableView. It works fine, but I don't want any table rows to display until the user starts typing in the search bar, so it is always filtered, and never will ALL matching rows display in the table.

```
var searchbar = Ti.UI.createSearchBar();

var tv = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: myData,
        search: searchbar,
        hideSearchOnSelection: false,
        filterAttribute: 'title',
});
```

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the tableView data to be empty when the page loads then set the data when the user starts typing in the searchbar, e.g.:

```
var searchbar = Ti.UI.createSearchBar();

searchbar.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    Ti.API.info("calling change event");
    var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];
    tv.data = tableData;
    //Remove this event listener so the data is only set once
    e.source.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
});

var tv = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: [{}],
        search: searchbar,
        hideSearchOnSelection: false,
        filterAttribute: 'title',
        height:Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow()

win.add(tv);
win.open();
```